# To Get ID of a dropdown in BeginItemCollection using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, kendo-dropdown

I got the main view with only one field and partial view with two kendo dropdowns.
This Partial view is called from the main view in a loop. In order to get the values from partial view in the controller, I use BeginItemCollection. I am getting all the values in a controller. The problem which I am facing is when the first drop down value is selected based on that the second dropdown should populate with values. For that purpose, I am using OnSelect event of the first dropdown and using ajax call retrieving the second dropdown values. But I need to empty the second dropdown values and bind with new values. For that, I need to get the Id of the second dropdown. As the dropdown is in BeginItemCollection the id is showing as **tdldata_c5e1d02a-f79e-4c91-adab-2e90f30d18ba__ServerModelId**. How to get the Id of a control in BeginItemCollection using Jquery.

```
  function onServerMakeSelect(e)
            {                
                var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
                serverMakeSelected = dataItem.Value;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'GetCascadeServerModelsWithoutSelection',
                    data: { "servermakes": serverMakeSelected },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {


                        var serverMakeDropdownList = $("#DropDownId").data("kendoDropDownList");
                        serverMakeDropdownList.dataSource.data({}); // clears dataSource
                        serverMakeDropdownList.text(""); // clears visible text
                        serverMakeDropdownList.value(""); // clears invisible value

                        $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                            debugger;
                            var optionTag = $('<option></option>');
                            $(optionTag).val(val.Value).text(val.Text);
                            $("#DropDownId").append(optionTag);

                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

The DropdownID in the code snippet I need in case of the dropdown in BeginItemCollection.

Below is the partial class implementation.

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("tdldata"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsAddApplication)

    <div id="tdlDataRow" class="tdlDataRow">
        <div class="admin-middle-section">
            <div class="admin-details">
                <div class="left-column">
                    <div class="admin-input">
                        <div class="label-input">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName):<em class="error-asterisk">*</em>
                        </div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="admin-input">
                        <div class="label-input">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurName):<em class="error-asterisk">*</em>
                        </div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SurName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="admin-input">
                            <div class="label-input">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServerMakeId):<em class="error-asterisk">*</em>
                            </div>
                            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ServerMakeId)
                                      .DataTextField("Text")
                                      .DataValueField("Value")
                                      .OptionLabel("Select Server Make")
                                      .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "serverMakeClass" +"~"+ Model.Id })
                                      .BindTo(Model.ServerMakes)
                                      .Events(e =>
                                      {
                                          e.Select("onServerMakeSelect");
                                      }))
                        </div>
                        <div class="admin-input">
                            <div class="label-input">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServerModelId):<em class="error-asterisk">*</em>
                            </div>
                            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ServerModelId)
                                  .OptionLabel("Select Server Model")
                                  .DataTextField("Text")
                                  .DataValueField("Value")
                                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "serverModelClass"+Model.Id })
                                  .BindTo(Model.ServerModels))
                       </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-column">
                    <div class="admin-input">
                        <div class="label-input">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsConfirmed)
                        </div>
                        @{
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsConfirmed)
                        }
                        @Html.Hidden("Id", @Model.Id)
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                            }
```

I given a class name for first ( Ex: "servermake~" + Model.Id ) and second dropdown list ( Ex: "servermodel" + Model.Id ).with a unique id. 
When on select of the first dropdown getting the first class name and then split with "~"  and then making the second control class name from the second part
of the string as Ex say, serverModel323. Hence I am getting the instance of the second drop down empty it. But after getting the second drop down value from the controller
the data is binding but all the values Ex If three items all three items are showing as a list and not showing as a dropdown control and on clicking all the previous value are also populating. So I create a new instance of drop down and assign it as the data source. In this case, `onsubmit` of form the data of the cascaded ie second drop down is getting null value in controller post method.

```
 $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: 'GetCascadeServerModelsWithoutSelection',
             data: { "serverMakeSelected": serverMakeSelected },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (data) {
                 var data3 = JSON.stringify(data);

                 var dropdownlist = $("." +                  
                      serverModelClassName).kendoDropDownList({
                     dataTextField: "text",
                     dataValueField: "value"
                 }).data().kendoDropDownList;
                 dropdownlist.dataSource.data(data3);
             }
         });
```

Comment: You can't easily (its a `Guid`), but why would you want to. Use a class name and relative selectors.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I added a classname for the second dropdown as below  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dashboard-table" }) and in ajax binding     var serverMakeDropdownList = $(".dashboard-table").data("kendoDropDownList"); But getting undefined error.

Comment: You need to then use relative selectors. You need to show the html - the `@Html.BeginCollectionItem(...)` bit and the code you using to generate the 2 dropdownlists inside it.

Comment: <input class="dashboard-table" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Server Model field is required." id="tdldata_40c37b8a-e750-43c6-b10b-1a0926dd86e1__ServerModelId" name="tdldata[40c37b8a-e750-43c6-b10b-1a0926dd86e1].ServerModelId" type="text" value="4" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">. This is the code generated for second dropdownlist with added class name class="dashboard-table".

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the information I asked in my last comment - i.e. the code for the partial view (and I do not need to see the html which is generated - I need to see your code for the partial)

Comment: @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ServerMakeId)
                                      .DataTextField("Text")
                                      .DataValueField("Value")
                                      .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "serverMakeClass" +"~"+ Model.Id })
                                      .BindTo(Model.ServerMakes)
                                      .Events(e =>
                                      {
                                          e.Select("onServerMakeSelect");
                                      }))  The text copied seems to long

Comment: You need to edit the **question**!